# Modify XHTML with XSLT

Tags: html, xslt

Good Day!  I have a need to modify an XHTML output with an XSLT.  Below is an excerpt of the XHTML output that I need to replace the bracketed tags like {Candidate.FullName} with data that I have in an XML.  Is there a simple way to do so?

```
<!DOCTYPE html
   PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" >

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial, Times New Roman, Verdana, Sans-Serif; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; margin: 0px; border-style: none; background-color: #ffffff">
    <div>
      <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
        {Other.CompanyLogos1}
      </p>
      <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
        &nbsp;
      </p>
      <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
        {Candidate.FullName}
      </p>
      <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
        {Candidate.Address}
      </p>
      <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
        {Candidate.Address2}
      </p>
      <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
        {Candidate.City}, {Candidate.State}&nbsp; {Candidate.Zipcode}
      </p>
      <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
        &nbsp;
      </p>
      <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
        Dear {Candidate.FirstName},
      </p>
      <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
        &nbsp;
      </p>
```

Comment: Please review: [mcve]

Comment: This will be possible only if the HTML is actually XHTML and is well-formed under the rules for XML.  An XSLT processor will not handle malformed XML.

Comment: I modified it to XHTML, it is starting to look a little more XML'ish